# Best way to find how many times an item in a list repeats in a row, in C#?

Tags: c#, list, iteration

Given a list, for example:
`List<int> _ = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8 };`

What would be the best / fastest / most efficient way to find how many times an item repeats in a row, in C#?
For this list, the result I'd be looking for is something that looks like this:

1 * 3

3 * 2

4 * 2

1 * 2

8 * 3

5 * 1

6 * 1

7 * 4

8 * 2

Doesn't have to be in this odd multiplication format, I think it makes it a bit easier to understand.

I've been trying looping over the List and comparing each item to the next, but I inevitably get stuck, and don't really know what to do.

Comment: Try to do it in one loop over the whole collection. A `List<int>` where you use the number as Index and otherwise count up. Or a `Dictionary<int, int>` could do this easily.

Comment: Please, for the love of all things you hold dear, don't name variables just `_`.

Comment: So you've instantiated the list... where is your attempt at iterating and keeping track of counts?  Can you [edit] in that portion of your code?

Comment: Show us your loop attempt so we can fix it.

Comment: A `for` loop is probably just as fast as any other method.

Comment: @Sach Unless it's a variable that's meant to be ignored.

Comment: @juharr still you can give it a better name.

Comment: @juharr More reason not to only use `_` as name. I reserve `_` as prefix for private instance variables. Stufff like backing fields of properties. If just `_` can resolve, that would be utterly messed up.

Comment: @Christopher I mean when you do something like `if(int.TryParse(x, out var _))` when you just want to know if a string parses to an int, but you don't need to do anything with the int value.  I'm not sure how that would mess up using it as a prefix.

Comment: You ask for "best", "fastest" and "most efficient", but those need not be the same thing. Give a metric by which "bestness" and "efficiency" can be measured, and remember that we often trade, say, worse memory usage for better speed.

Comment: Also, asking for "fastest" is seldom a good idea; the fastest way to solve the problem is to build custom hardware dedicated to solving this problem; you can do so for under a billion dollars, but you're probably not looking for that solution. No one cares about *fastest*. We care about *fast enough for the user's requirements*. So instead of saying "fastest", tell us what your performance budget is and how close you are to meeting it.

Comment: Here's a [LINQ](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FsLEya) version for an alternative than what was posted.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah sorry. I left it pretty ambigous because I didn't really mind whether the program was fast, efficient, or anything else. Just any answer really, guess it was a bad idea.

Comment: @Sach I know lol, it's not part of any actual code and is just a placeholder name for this post.

Comment: @BBonless: Please don't ask questions if you're not interested in the answers; the people volunteering to answer questions could be spending time answering questions where people do care about the answer.

Comment: @EricLippert What makes you think I'm not interested in the answer? What Rufus said was helpful and I'm definitely thankful for it. I'm just saying I didn't mind how the program was optimized, whether quick or efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just loop through the list, and for each item I would see if the current item is the same as the previous item. If it is, increment a count variable and continue. If it isn't, capture the previous item and the count and reset the previous item to the current item and the count to `1`.

One way to make this easier is to create a simple class that holds a `Value` and a `Count`, so that we can return a list of these that represent the items in the list:

```
public class Item<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public int Count  { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Value} * {Count}";
    }
}
```

Then we can write a generic method that takes in a list and returns a list of the class above, using the strategy mentioned in the beginning:

```
public static List<Item<T>> GetItemCounts<T>(List<T> input)
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    var itemCounts = new List<Item<T>>();
    Item<T> currentItem = null;

    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        // If we haven't set an item yet, do so
        if (currentItem == null)
        {
            currentItem = new Item<T> {Value = item, Count = 1};
        }
        // If the current item is the same as this item, increment the count
        else if (currentItem.Value.Equals(item))
        {
            currentItem.Count++;
        }
        // This is a new item, so save the current item and create a new one
        else
        {
            itemCounts.Add(currentItem);
            currentItem = new Item<T> { Value = item, Count = 1 };
        }
    }

    // Add the last item
    if (currentItem != null) itemCounts.Add(currentItem);

    return itemCounts;
}
```

Now, using your sample input, we can use the method above to get our results:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<int> {1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8};

    // Get our item counts and output them to the console window
    GetItemCounts(items).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Woah. Thanks for the detailed explaination despite my lackluster wording! This helps alot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm that works.

The idea is this; iterate through the list until we reach the penultimate item, and at each iteration see if current items is the same as the next. If so, increment the `repeat` variable, which is initialized to `1`. Otherwise, print the count of the current item and reset `repeat`.

```
var numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7 };

var repeat = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1])
    {
        repeat++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1}", numbers[i], repeat);
        repeat = 1;
    }

    if (i == numbers.Count - 2)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1}", numbers[i], repeat);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1}", numbers[i + 1], 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The additional `if` at the end is to deal with the special case of last item. Since we iterate the loop only up to the penultimate item, we need to check the last item separately.